# http://localhost:8080/ROOT/ not found 404

Tags: tomcat

I have just installed xammp in my computer, and to test it, I starte tomcat by

> catalina.bat run

And once running, went to the link `http://localhost:8080/ROOT/` or `http://localhost:8080/host-manager/`. But none of them are found, getting a 404 error.
Is this normal?? When I had my own web application, will `http://localhost:8080/myApplication` run without problem??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROOT` is not a valid context name. The application deployed in the `ROOT` folder is accessinble via `http://localhost:8080`. Your application should work fine if properly deployed (war file placed in `webapps`)

Btw, you'd better start it with `startup.bat`

Comment: Thanks, I had lot of problems with mysql, that's why I ask again. I run catalinta.bat run to see posible erros in concole directly, instead of going to log files